# How do I capture the key pressed in XAML when using interactivity EventName=PreviewKeyDown in a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, keypress

I have a DataGrid that has many rows in it.  I want to capture the keyboard key or keys pressed and execute the appropriate code depending on key pressed.  I want the user to be able to do CTRL-D to delete a row or press the DELETE key.  I also need to pass the DataGrid element as a parameter to the code called.  Here is what I am doing in my XAML.

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.TargetFieldsKeyDownCommand, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vw:MappingDataView}}}" >
        <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
             <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource KeyPressConverter}">
                  <Binding Source="Delete" />
                  <Binding ElementName="dtTDGrid" />
             </MultiBinding>
        </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

I want to replace this, `<Binding Source="Delete" />`, with the actual key pressed.  Is there away to do this using Interactivity in XAML or do I need to handle the key pressed differently?  Does anyone of any examples of what I am trying to do?

Using the MultiBinding of Interactivity is all I have found for passing 2 or more command parameters to the Event called.  If there is a better way to call the Event Handler while passing multiple parameters please let me know.

Comment: If you want to pass the actual key being pressed to the command, you should handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event in your own custom command action and then pass it to the command. There is no support for doing this in pure XAML.